Docker Containers Can't Resolve Domain Names on Bridge Network
Help Needed: Docker Containers Can't Resolve Domain Names on Bridge Network
Hi everyone,
I'm having trouble with my Docker setup on my home server. My containers on the bridge network can ping IP addresses but cannot resolve domain names. However, when using the host network, everything works fine. Here are the details:
Issue Description
When I enter a container using the bridge network and try to ping an IP address (e.g., 8.8.8.8), it works fine. However, attempting to ping a domain name (e.g., google.com) results in a temporary failure in name resolution.
Steps Taken

Ping IP Address:
root@pihole:/# ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=113 time=47.4 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=113 time=46.9 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=113 time=46.8 ms


Ping Domain Name:
root@pihole:/# ping google.com
ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution



Configuration Details

Host DNS Configuration:
root@tanix-tx6:~# cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 192.168.1.1
nameserver 2001:4860:4860::8888
nameserver 2001:4860:4860::8844


Docker Network:
root@tanix-tx6:~# docker network inspect bridge
[
    {
        "Name": "bridge",
        "Id": "70bb26ec3707789535bb7d3330dc37377a1c17a14816bead670221c9d9b93580",
        "Created": "2024-05-25T08:44:25.063899697Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.17.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "78134bf84c7ac332bcbf06b9c2b38463f42b9dfec2882a9a4f1ec79c0273f3b8": {
                "Name": "memos",
                "EndpointID": "df06ce0ce691d0e8a4f78972e41160047a621ae44d216a604fbf3238a94e04b9",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "986bd055e8dfa4800a9aec4dfe0b7da669d57aa0a39c87511ce6fbf795ef7ffe": {
                "Name": "deluge",
                "EndpointID": "a9270181c59b93cea615e29bf6988b932c566749cdff6545f487a6010569ee31",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.bridge.default_bridge": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4": "0.0.0.0",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker0",
            "com.docker.network.driver.mtu": "1500"
        },
        "Labels": {}
    }
]



System Information

Docker Version: (e.g., 20.10.7)
Operating System: (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS ARM64 (Armbian) )

Troubleshooting Steps

Checked /etc/resolv.conf on the host and containers.
Tried setting custom DNS servers in Docker daemon configuration.
Restarted Docker service.


Can you extract and provide a [mcve], both code and required manual steps? Also, what does "enter a container" mean specifically? As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Also remember that Stack Overflow is specifically about programming questions.  Unless your application is specifically sending ICMP packets (why?) it doesn't seem like a question around ping(1) will be related to your application code.
